# How do I optimize MYSQL select statements which execute 4000 times in total in a table with 50M rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

This is how my code looks like:

```
foreach ($instruments as $instrument) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT date, adjusted_close, close FROM ehd_historical_data WHERE exchange = ? AND symbol = ? AND date >= ? ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute([xyzToExchange($instrument2), xyzToSymbol($instrument2), $startDate]);
    $data1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT date, adjusted_close, close FROM ehd_historical_data WHERE exchange = ? AND symbol = ? ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute([xyzToExchange($instrument2), xyzToSymbol($instrument2)]);
    $data2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

There are around 2000 instruments that are string in this format "NASDAQ:AAPL".

It currently takes 7 seconds to complete since the database has around 50 million rows.

So far:

1. I have set INDEX for exchange, symbol and date together.
2. Set another INDEX for exchange and symbol together.

I want to ask further what can I do to optimize this query.

Note:

1. The function which this code is part of tries to find the price difference and the percent change between the start date and today's date. The start date can be anything like 6 months ago, 3 months ago.
2. I tried merging them in one large query and then executing them. Still same problem.

**Update:**

1. EXPLAIN for both queries

[image]
[image]

2. Table Schema

```
    CREATE TABLE `ehd_historical_data` (
    `exchange` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `symbol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `open` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
    `high` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
    `low` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
    `close` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
    `adjusted_close` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
    `volume` decimal(20,0) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


    ALTER TABLE `ehd_historical_data`
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `exchange_2` (`exchange`,`symbol`,`date`),
    ADD KEY `exchange` (`exchange`),
    ADD KEY `date` (`date`),
    ADD KEY `symbol` (`symbol`),
    ADD KEY `exchange_3` (`exchange`,`symbol`);
    COMMIT;
```

Comment: pls show us the **EXPLAIN** of your queries and the table structure

Comment: Just as a general use of prepared statements, prepare them outside the loop (with different variable names) and execute them multiple times in the loop.

Comment: @NigelRen Tried that. No real performance improvement. But thanks for the tip though, it's better that way.

Comment: Do you have more than one exchange?

Comment: Is that "7 seconds" for APPL?  Or for 2000 instruments?

Comment: @RickJames Dozen of exchanges. 7 seconds for 2000 instruments.

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting both rows in a single query using `row_number()`

```
select * 
from (
  SELECT date, adjusted_close, close,
    row_number() over(order by date desc) rn1,
    row_number() over(order by date asc) rn2
  FROM ehd_historical_data 
  WHERE exchange = ? AND symbol = ? AND date >= ? 
) t
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1
```

You may also request all symbols at once. Note a `partition` clause

```
select * 
from (
  SELECT exchange, symbol, date, adjusted_close, close,
    row_number() over(partition by exchange, symbol order by date desc) rn1,
    row_number() over(partition by exchange, symbol order by date asc) rn2
  FROM ehd_historical_data 
  WHERE ((exchange = 'NASDAQ' AND symbol = 'AAPL') OR (exchange = 'NASDAQ' AND symbol = 'MSFT') OR (exchange = 'NASDAQ' AND symbol = 'TSLA')) AND date >= ? 
) t
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1
```

Comment: I assume in best case, it will save 50% time so 50% of 7 seconds = 3.5 seconds. Is it possible to finish it under 1 second (ideally 150ms)?

Comment: You can also build a where clause to get all symbols of  `$instruments` at once `..AND symbol in (s1,s2, ..)`

Comment: Do you know how to modify this query to have multiple exchange:symbol pair in once?

Comment: Try creating a functional index on `concat(excange, ':', symbol)` and search by  `concat(excange, ':', symbol) in ('NASDAQ:AAPL', ..)`

Comment: I modified your query like this https://pastebin.com/Gi65ncKD. It's only returns 2 rows instead of 6 rows. Any idea? I am not expert in SQL at this high level.

Comment: @CodePanda, see the edited answer.

Comment: I tried the second query today. It takes forever to finish when I pass 2000 instruments at once.

Comment: I also tested the first query. Looping through it 2000 times was twice as slow as the using the simpler queries in my examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your index (`exchange`,`symbol`,`date`) is optimal for both of those `SELECTs`, so let's dig into other causes for sluggishness.

```
CREATE TABLE `ehd_historical_data` (
`exchange` varchar(255) NOT NULL,   -- Don't use 255 if you don't need it
`symbol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,     -- ditto
`date` date NOT NULL,
`open` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,     -- overkill
`high` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
`low` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
`close` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
`adjusted_close` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
`volume` decimal(20,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
   CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;  -- probably all are ascii


ALTER TABLE `ehd_historical_data`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `exchange_2` (`exchange`,`symbol`,`date`),  -- Change to PRIMARY KEY
ADD KEY `exchange` (`exchange`),  -- redundant, DROP
ADD KEY `date` (`date`),
ADD KEY `symbol` (`symbol`),
ADD KEY `exchange_3` (`exchange`,`symbol`);  -- redundant, DROP
COMMIT;
```

Have another table of symbols; use a `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` in this table.

`decimal(20,10)` takes 10 bytes; I know of no symbol that needs that much precision or range.

The above comments are aimed at making the table smaller.  If the table is currently bigger than will fit in cache, I/O will be the cause of sluggishness.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size?

How fast does this run?  (I'm thinking there might be a way to get all 2000 results in a single SQL.  This might be a component of it.)

```
        SELECT  exchange, symbol,
                MIN(date) AS date1,
                MAX(date) AS date2
            FROM  ehd_historical_data 
            WHERE date > ?
            GROUP BY  exchange, symbol
```

That would be `JOINed` back to the table twice, once for each date.

Comment: Hi Rick, I will try this later today (it's a side-project for me). innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G, RAM is 64GB. It's local environment, but I have plenty of free RAM most of the time. Earlier today, I converted exchange to ENUM for my personal reasons. I need `decimal(20,10)` for crypto exchanges. They have weird long numbers after decimal point.

Comment: Quick question: Why are you asking me to drop `exchange`, `exchange+symbol` INDEX while keeping the `date` and `symbol` INDEX? I sometime query using `exchange+symbol` WHERE condition.

Comment: @CodePanda - See `exchange_2` (or the PK, as I suggest).  It starts with the same two columns in the same order.  Note also, `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` does not handle the same set of cases as `INDEX(a,b)`.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql